# XACML Rule for Time In Range as a Condition

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, alfa

I would like to write a rule that use a condition statement to build an 
XACML function: "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:function:time-in-range" using the ALFA language syntax. For reason of easy obligation handling, I would prefer to use it inside condition function, and not in a target expression.
Is this possible? I did not find any reference to it in the manual.

at @David Brossard. Following the scheme below I've tested the policy using the following ALFA code:

```
namespace com.ibm.XACML {
import Attributes.*
import attributes.*
import com.ibm.XACML.Attributes.*
  attribute currentTime {
            id = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:current-time"
            type = time
            category = environmentCat
        }   

function timeInRange = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:function:time-in-range" : time time time -> boolean                
// lowerBound = "09:00:00-03:00"
// upperBound = "18:00:00-03:00"    
// current-time = "02:00:00-03:00" decision permit 
// current-time = "10:00:00-03:00" decision permit  
// current-time = "22:00:00-03:00" decision permit      

policy checkTimeInRange{
    apply firstApplicable
    rule allowWithinRange{
        permit
        condition timeInRange(timeOneAndOnly(currentTime), timeOneAndOnly(timeBag("09:00:00-03:00":time)), timeOneAndOnly(timeBag("19:00:00-03:00":time)))
        }
    }
}
```

The syntax validation runs OK, but there is an error in the evaluation results that return from the WSO2 PDP code, giving a "Permit" for all of the three tests, 02:00:00, 10:00:00 and 22:00:00.

I've isolated the issue. The WSO2 Try-It tool generates "String" as default while the XACML expects a time data type. To fix it, a manual request must be placed and the logic shown by @David Brossard worked perfectly. Here a sample request, generating a "Permit".

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:current-time" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time">11:00:00-03:00</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Request>
```

The "TimeInRange" function combined with a Condition statement is very helpful.

Comment: What manual are you referring to? WSO2 doesn't support ALFA...

Comment: Dear @David Brossard. Referring to to .doc specifications "Abbreviated Language for Authorization Version 1.0" for ALFA language, working draft 01.  I'm rewriting some XACML polices under the ALFA eclipse code editor. The construction of condition is useful, its more programmer and code friendly, due to its support to common algorithms, like boolean logic. The time in range function would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [XACML standard](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-cs-01-en.html#_Toc265751150) I can read

> **urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:function:time-in-range**
>
> This function SHALL take three arguments of data-type [time](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time) and SHALL return a [boolean](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean).  It SHALL return **True** if the first argument falls in the range defined inclusively by the second and third arguments. Otherwise, it SHALL return “False”.
>
> Regardless of its value, the third argument SHALL be interpreted as a time that is equal to, or later than by less than twenty-four hours, the second argument.  If no time zone is provided for the first argument, it SHALL use the default time zone at the context handler.  If no time zone is provided for the second or third arguments, then they SHALL use the time zone from the first argument.

ALFA also has that function. It is defined as

```
function timeInRange = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:function:time-in-range" : time time time -> boolean
```

To use it, simply do:

```
policy checkTimeInRange{
    apply firstApplicable
    rule allowWithinRange{
        permit
        condition timeInRange(timeOneAndOnly(currentTime), timeOneAndOnly(lowerBound), timeOneAndOnly(upperBound))
    }
}
```

Note that if you are missing any of these values, the PDP will reply with **Indeterminate**.

Comment: The ALFA code published above was accepted as valid, but its simulation did not return the expected results under the WSO2 PDP.  See my test code posted at the initial section.

Comment: What error did you get? Maybe WSO2 doesn't support time